# WPF binding from new window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, binding

I need to fix bindings after changing user control for stand alone window. Basically right now i have two windows using ShowDialog(), i connected new window to new data context

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModels:DatabaseDesignViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

However now I have trouble with binding buttons to commands from root view which is main window.

This is how i tried to solve it without luck:

```
 <MenuItem Header="Go to design mode"
                  Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Views:RootView}}, Path=DataContext.OKCommand}"/>
```

Comment: Is MenuItem is part of ContextMenu?

Comment: `FindAncestor` won't work, because since you moved to standalone window, `RootView` (a parent window or it's part, as far as I understand) is not an "ancestor". Each window has its own logical and visual trees.

Comment: @Dennis is there a way to access those commands if they are in different logical and visual tree

Comment: @user5606505: it is hard to say, since I don't know, how do you create your view models and windows. First of all, it may be some architectural issue, when you need a commands from parent view model. Second, if you really need it, I'd bring something like `MainViewModel Parent { get; }` into child view model. This will make binding trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First - I agree with Dennis, you should overthink your architecture, but of course there is an answer to your request:

1. Create an attached property like this:

   ```
   public class AttachedProperties
   {
       public static Window GetParentWindow( DependencyObject obj )
       {
           return (Window)obj.GetValue( ParentWindowProperty );
       }
       public static void SetParentWindow( DependencyObject obj, Window value )
       {
           obj.SetValue( ParentWindowProperty, value );
       }
       public static readonly DependencyProperty ParentWindowProperty =
           DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached( "ParentWindow", typeof( Window ), typeof( AttachedProperties ), new PropertyMetadata( null ) );
   }
   ```
2. Add the following Code to your child windows xaml.cs:

   ```
   protected override void OnActivated( EventArgs e )
       {
           base.OnActivated( e );
           this.SetValue( AttachedProperties.ParentWindowProperty, Owner );
       }
   ```
3. In your child windows xaml, you can use the following binding syntax:

   ```
   <Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.ChildWindow"
           xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
           xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourApplicationNamespace"
           x:Name="Self">
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=Self, Path=(local:AttachedProperties.ParentWindow).DataContext.SomeProperty}" />
   </Window>
   ```